# Changing default window/taskbar colors in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, colors, themes

Is there any way to change default window colors for light or dark theme in Windows 10?

[image: Example window]

Let's say I want to change color #1 and #4 (which are probably the same) or the color #3. How do I do it? Maybe there is some hack by patching windows registry/files? Same question for taskbar color. For example in dark theme it's black, how do I change it's color? I know there is a way to make taskbar of "accent" color, but I want to be able to change the default black color and set it to arbitrary color which is not necessarily equal to current accent color. What I've tried so far is messing with `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors` registry key. There is even neat "Classic Color Panel" software for that, but I was not able to find/change color #1, #3 or #4 there.

[image: Classic Color Panel]

I was only able to find and change color #2 which is named "Window". Please advise how can I change colors of other panels/menus, etc. Thanks.

Comment: Personalization, Themes allows custom colors so of which affect task bar and menu titles.  I use these so they do work.

Comment: But are you able to change the colors marked 1,3,4 on my screenshot? I don't see such options in Personalization/Themes.

Comment: I use the custom colors for Title bars and borders.  I then use the Windows colors in the window itself.  I don't think you can otherwise change them.